# Split chained commands into commands

Tags: shell

Is there a command that takes as input another command (which may or may not include the control operators `&&`, `||`, `;` and possibly others that might be relevant) and breaks the command into its "sub commands"?

For example:

```
echo 1 && ls --invalid-option 2>/dev/null || echo 3
```

Would be broken down into:

- `echo 1`
- `ls --invalid-option 2>/dev/null` or possibly `ls --invalid-option`
- `echo 3`

Comment: What is a "token" for your use case? In conventional terms `echo` and `1` are separate tokens.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Thanks, I wasn't aware. I edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's clear. I don't have an answer to it - parsing shell is notoriously complicated - but someone might know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing shell syntax is a *huge* job and is usually not easily done.

However, if you're fine with running the line once, then you can let the shell do it, with `set -x`:

```bsh
wsl@win10:~ $ set -x
wsl@win10:~ $ echo 1 && ls haha &> /dev/null; pwd
+ echo 1
1
+ ls --color=auto haha
+ pwd
/home/wsl
wsl@win10:~ $
```

As you can note, there's one caveat: `alias` expansion (all expansion, actually).

To extract the actual commands would probably be an interesting little after-school task for readers (hint: lines starting with a plus and a space).

Answer (score 0):

Using sed in a very basic, limited approach:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Input data file $FILE:"
head $FILE

pl " Input data file $FILE, invisibles marked:"
cat -A $FILE

pl " Results:"
sed -e 's/[      ]*&&[   ]*/\n/g' -e 's/[       ]*||[   ]*/\n/g' $FILE
```

producing:

```
-----
 Input data file data2:
one-space && next-one || last-one

one-TAB &&      next-tab        ||      last-tab

mixed-tabs-space         &&             next-mixed        ||    last-mixed

-----
 Input data file data2, invisibles marked:
one-space && next-one || last-one$
$
one-TAB^I&&^Inext-tab^I||^Ilast-tab$
$
mixed-tabs-space ^I && ^I^Inext-mixed^I  ||  ^Ilast-mixed$

-----
 Results:
one-space
next-one
last-one

one-TAB
next-tab
last-tab

mixed-tabs-space
next-mixed
last-mixed
```

In a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-7-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.11 (jessie) 
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

The [] enclose a TAB and a space, so any number of such white-space characters are allowed. This does not take into account quoted strings, etc.

Best wishes ... cheers, drl